# diffrence between property and attribute in c# uml

Tags: c#, oop, properties, uml, class-diagram

i am trying to make a UML for a c# project.
all the references for the UML shows that you need to define attribute and operations for a class in class diagram.
but i have written c# codes a lot and i know for a class you need to know the operations and properties. we have attribute in C# but it is not that important for creating a class.
is it right that attributes is actually the properties in UML for c#?
thank you.

Comment: That is my understanding too. Property is a common term for a data field on an object in an OOP programming language. The term field is more common in a database context, although attribute is also used when creating a data model. UML is more abstract, for modeling information systems in general. So it is partly a matter of jargon and partly a matter of abstraction level. Property is a trait of something that is well defined in an OOP context, attribute is the more general implimentation-independent "belongs to" relationship.